# Linking LAPACK and BLAS libraries to a C++ program using Armadillo, in Ubuntu 18.04: What changes should I make in the Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, armadillo, lapack, blas

I am a beginner in programming in C++. I have a program in C++ that uses Armadillo (a linear algebra library that uses LAPACK and BLAS), which is directly included in my scripts. The functionality of Armadillo that does not depend on LAPACK and BLAS works fine, however, operations like matrix multiplication (that depends on LAPACK) does not work. I have installed LAPACK and BLAS independently using “sudo apt-get install”.
I get the following error on running make:

```
.objs/main.o: In function `void arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const*, int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/translate_blas.hpp:38: undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgemv_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
generic.mk:51: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I have kept the LAPACK and BLAS shared libraries (liblapack.so and libblas.so) inside the local directory of my program.

I have attached the relevant portion (as per my understanding) of the Makefile

```
OBJS = main.o vector_HS.o basis.o state.o model.o lattice.o     
CLEAN_RM =
LIBS = -llapack -lblas -ltmglib
```

where I have added -llapack and -lblas manually. I have seen several questions on this topic, but most answers involve the use of cmake which I do not understand at this point. Could anyone help me to make the required changes in the Makefile, so that I can successfully use LAPACK and BLAS in my program?